# Passing Multiple Values to a single Crystal Reports parameter from VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, parameter-passing

I am using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2012 with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio.

I have a parameter in a Crystal Report that can accept multiple values (for instance:  Regions).  How do I pass multiple values to that single parameter from vb.net?  The values would be coming from selections from a ListBox.

Sorry if this is answered elsewhere.  I have tried many searches all over internet with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

### Bob

As asked for, here is code from where I select a single value from ComboBox.  The Parameter in the Crystal Report is BuyDate. I just am not sure how to make it for multiple values.  If you need more details, just let me know.

```
Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

Dim SSBuy = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument()
Dim Filepath = "\\filepath\Report By Buy Date.rpt"

SSBuy.Load(Filepath)

crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
crParameterFieldDefinitions = SSBuy.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("BuyDate")
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

crParameterValues.Clear()
crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)

crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
SSBuyForm.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = SSBuy

SSBuyForm.Refresh()
SSBuyForm.Show()
```

Comment: Show what you have first ..

Comment: I included the code above, which is code that works when sending a single value to a parameter.

Comment: What error you've got ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the answer on the SAP website.  Here is the link to the article, for anyone else who may need it.

[Pass Multiple Values to a Parameter](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1951788)

Also, here is the actual code I used, which runs a report based on PO#'s selected from a ListBox.

```
Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

Dim SSPO = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument()
Dim Filepath = "\\Filepath\Report Download By PO #.rpt"

SSPO.Load(Filepath)

crParameterFieldDefinitions = SSPO.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions("PO#")
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

Dim Count As Integer = POList1.SelectedItems.Count

For i = 0 To Count - 1
     If i > 0 Then
          crParameterDiscreteValue = Nothing
     End If
     crParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
     crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = POList1.SelectedItems(i)
     crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
Next

crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
SSPoForm.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = SSPO

SSPoForm.Refresh()
SSPoForm.Show()
```